# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'WebElement'

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, promise, protractor

Context: I am updating the e2e tests to use async/ await. When trying to update the function (with return type promise.Promise < WebElement>) to be async and calling it from the test it will result in a TS error.

Current implementation:

```
export function waitUntilElementIsVisible(element: ElementFinder): promise.Promise<WebElement> {
    browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element))

    return browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element))
}
```

Tried solution:

```
export async function waitUntilElementIsVisible(element: ElementFinder): Promise<WebElement> {
   await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element))

   return browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element))
}
```

And the function is called like:

```
it('should wait until element is visible, async () =>
     await waitUntilElementIsVisible( error_page)
     expect(web element displayed)
})
```

And I am facing the following issue:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'WebElement'.  Property 'getDriver' is missing in type '{}'.
```

Am I doing this correctly? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you send how object `error_page` looks like?

Comment: This means that this isn't what `browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element))` returns. Therefore, your type annotation is likely wrong.

Comment: @PrzemyslawJanBeigert  error_page object looks like:

`class ErrorPage {
getErrorPage(): ElementFinder {
       return $('.error-page')
   }
}`


`await waitUntilElementIsVisible(ErrorPage.getErrorPage())`

Comment: you missed `await` in the `return` statement. It should be `return await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function should look like so:

```
export async function waitUntilElementIsVisible(element: ElementFinder): Promise<any> {
   await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element))
}
```

First of all, if we'll look closer at [visibilityOf code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.1/lib/expectedConditions.ts) we will see that it calls `presenceOf` by itself, so you don't need that additional check.

Secondable, there is no need to return anything in such case, moreover, as [browser.wait docs says](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait), it returns `!webdriver.promise.Promise<T>`, but I don't think it could be `WebElement`, it returns what `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf` returns.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but need more space than in comment

I'm confused, you saying you're calling the function like this

```
it('should wait until element is visible, async () =>
     await waitUntilElementIsVisible( error_page)
     expect(web element displayed)
})
```

Then your object is

```
class ErrorPage { 
  getErrorPage(): ElementFinder { 
    return $('.error-page') 
  } 
}
```

Now I thought everything is clear, ErrorPage is object (`{}`), but you need an elementFinder. So what you need is

```
ErrorPage.getErrorPage() // instead of error_page
```

But in the comment you're stating this is the way you call it

```
await waitUntilElementIsVisible(ErrorPage.getErrorPage())
```

So which way do you use? `error_page` or `ErrorPage.getErrorPage()`